# Does taking the address of a slice element implies a copy of the element in Go?

Tags: go, pointers, struct, slice

Let's say a `Go 1.18` program has a **quite heavy** `struct`, for which copying is to be considered costly:

```golang
type MyStruct struct {
    P string
    // a lot of properties
}
```

Now let's define a function, taking a **slice** of such elements as input parameter, which goal is to update properties of each slice element:

```golang
func myFunc(sl []MyStruct) {
    for i := range sl {
        p := &sl[i]       // <-- HERE
        p.P = "bar"
        // other properties mutations
    }
}
```

At the `<-- HERE` mark, is the Golang compiler making a **temporary copy** of the slice element into the loop's scope, or is it taking the address of the slice element **in-place**?

The idea is to avoid copying the whole slice element.

A working example: https://go.dev/play/p/jHOC2DauyrQ?v=goprev

Comment: if you are modifying the original array, why are you not passing the array address instead? because this way you will need to return and assign the result from the function

Comment: @M-Raw The `sl` parameter is a slice, not an array, and passing a slice shares the backing array. Modifying the elements inside `myFunc()` will be observable / visible at the caller without returning the slice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&sl[i]` does not copy the slice element, it just evaluates to the address of the `i`<sup>th</sup> element.

<sup>Slice elements act as variables, and `&x` evaluates to the [address](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Address_operators) of the `x` variable. Think about it: since `&sl[i]` is the address of the `i`th element, the address does not need nor use the struct value, why would it make a copy?</sup>

If your slices are so big that you're worried about the performance impact of (implicit) copies, you really should consider storing pointers in the slice in the first place, and that way you can make your loop and accessing elements much simpler without having to worry about copies:

```
func myFunc(sl []*MyStruct) {
    for _, v := range sl {
        v.P = "bar"
        // other properties mutations
    }
}
```

Also note that if your slice holds non-pointers, and you want to change a field of a slice element, indexing the slice and referring to the field also does not involve copying the struct element:

```
func myFunc(sl []MyStruct) {
    for i := range sl {
        sl[i].P = "bar"
        // other properties mutations
    }
}
```

Yes, this may be more verbose and may be less efficient if you have to modify multiple fields (but compilers may also recognize and optimize the evaluation of multiple `sl[i]` expressions).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it confirms what I wasn't sure about such manipulations. I knew about the "slice of pointers" trick, but it is not always possible to deal with slices of pointers instead of slices of elements of concrete type.